# Firebase getting all docs from collections and docs of subcollection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have this schema :

[image: schema i have]

And I try to put a table with the documents and just below the documents of the subcollection, something similar to this:

[image: what I want]

I'm using this code, but in practice it doesn't display the data in order, it first puts the documents in the collection together and then the docs for the subcollections, I get this:

[image: i am getting this]

```
getDocs(collection(db, "users")).then(docSnap => {
  let table = document.getElementById('myTable')
  table.innerHTML = ''

  docSnap.forEach((doc) => {

    let data = doc.data();
    let row = `<tr>                           
                        <td>${data.contador}</td>
                        <td>${data.email}</td>
                        <td>${data.pass}</td>
                        </tr>`;

    let table = document.getElementById('myTable')
    table.innerHTML += row // 

    getDocs(collection(db, "users", doc.id, "fcm_tokens")).then(docSnapFCM => {
      docSnapFCM.forEach((docFCM) => {
        let data2 = docFCM.data();
        let row2 = `<tr class="table-success">
                        <td>${data2.contador}</td>
                        <td>${data2.device_type}</td>
                        <td>${data2.fcm_token}</td>
                        </tr>`;

        table.innerHTML += row2

      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `forEach` is running synchronous and the fetch request from `getDocs` is running asynchronous. The asynchronous code (the `getDocs` function just takes more time to execute than the `forEach` loop does which causes that all your user rows are added to your table before the answer comes from your firestore.

To solve this issue you have to `await` each `getDocs` call in your `forEach` function with the `async`/`await` keywords and `Promise.all`.

Example:

*Not a one to one copy of your code but I hope it helps you learning*

```
const createTable = async () => {
    // gather your user data
    const users = (await getDocs(collection(db, 'users')).docs.map((doc) => doc.data());


    // loop over the user data in async
    Promise.all(
        users.forEach(async (user) => {
            // do your table adding stuff here
            let row = '<tr>...'

            const subcollection = (await getDocs(collection(db, "users", doc.id, "fcm_tokens"))).docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
        
            // do your subcollections table adding stuff here
            subcollection.forEach((doc) => {
                // some table row adding with your data
            });
        });
    )
}
```